# Detect end of line while reading from a text-file C++

Tags: c++, file-io

I am trying to read a text-file based using the `>>` stream operator, but this seems to read the file word by word:

```
void printFile(char filename[])
{
    ifstream input;
    input.open(filename);

    char output[50];
    if (input.is_open()) {
        while (!input.eof()) {
            input >> output;
            cout << output << endl;
        }
    }
    else cout << "File is not open!";

    input.close();
    cout << endl;
}
```

The only problem with this is that it won't print out the linebreaks.

Please note that I'm still learning C++ and the goal is to achieve this without `using string`s (so without `getline`). Is there any way of doing this, or is it simply impossible?

Comment: Is the goal just to not getline? You could read in by character instead which would prevent losing '\n'

Comment: Read the file using getline(), that way you don't need to worry about line breaks. And read https://latedev.wordpress.com/2012/12/04/all-about-eof to see why not to loop on eof().

Comment: @NeilButterworth I think you missed a part of my question

Comment: @odin Thanks, that worked!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911822/using-istream-iterator-and-reading-from-standard-input-or-file

Comment: @NeilButterworth About the goal being not using strings and getline

Comment: Why would you avoid using them, but use iostreams, which are far more complex? Wherever you are learning C++, it's a bad place.

Comment: Don't use `.eof()` use: `while (input >> output)`

Comment: @NeilButterworth We're challenged to solve this with just chars. Of course we also learn to use strings in other scenario's. It's basically just learning to think out of the box

Comment: Thinking out of the box would be implementing this with `double`s. What you are doing is learning 1970's style C. Good from a historical point of view, but not so useful if your long-term goals include employment. Not much work at the moment for historical computing, but 2038 is rapidly approaching and 2000 was a real shot in the arm for COBOL experts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @odin I found the solution by reading the file by character instead of by word:

```
void printFile(char filename[])
{
    char ch;
    fstream fin(filename, fstream::in);
    while (fin >> noskipws >> ch) {
        cout << ch;
    }
    fin.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can identify an end of a line as follow

```
int main(){

    char ch;
    fstream fin("filename.txt", fstream::in);
    while(fin >> noskipws >> ch){
        if(ch == '\n') {   // detects the end of the line
            cout << "This is end of the line" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How is this very different from the existing answer?

Comment: @ArdentCoder The existing answer is reading the file character by character. But we can detect any character using the 'if' statement.

Comment: I said "very different" as the existing answer was given  by the OP himself.